# Black screen for application build with JavafXPorts, finally it stops

Tags: javafxports

I am trying to make my application run on an android device by using the jfxmobile-plugin.

Finally an

```
gradle androidInstall
```

passes throught and the apk is installed on my device.
My gradle file is this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

mainClassName = 'de.package.of.application.ClientApp'

dependencies {

    compile 'com.annimon:stream:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.2.0'

    androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-android:3.0.0'
    iosRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-ios:3.0.0'
    desktopRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-desktop:3.0.0'   

    compile fileTree(dir: 'target/dependencies', include: '*.jar')
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'target/dependencies', include: '*.jar')    
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

jfxmobile {
    ios {
        forceLinkClasses = ['ensemble.**.*']
    }
    android {
        //manifest = 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        compileSdkVersion = '21'
        androidSdk='C:/Tools/android-sdk-windows'

        packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        //... some more excludes

    }

        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize '3g'
            keepRuntimeAnnotatedClasses false
        }
    }
}
```

When the app is started on the device a black screen appears for some seconds and then a message pops up: 'application stopped'.
I connected to the device with 
    adb logcat -v threadtime
The log contains several exceptions which I will list here:

```
01-15 18:11:09.356 16952 16952 E dalvikvm: Unable to extract+optimize DEX from '/data/data/de.package.of.application/code_cache/secondary-dexes/de.package.of.application-1.apk.classes6.zip'
```

......

```
01-15 18:11:09.366 16952 16952 W MultiDex: Exception in makeDexElement

01-15 18:11:09.366 16952 16952 W MultiDex: java.io.IOException: unable to open DEX file
```

.....

```
01-15 18:11:09.376 16952 16952 E MultiDex: Multidex installation failure

01-15 18:11:09.376 16952 16952 E MultiDex: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: Field dexElementsSuppressedExceptions not found in class dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
```

.....

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: Multi dex installation failed (Field dexElementsSuppressedExceptions not found in class dalvik.system.PathClassLoader).
...
01-15 18:11:09.386 16952 16952 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Multi dex installation failed (Field dexElementsSuppressedExceptions not found in class dalvik.system.PathClassLoader).

01-15 18:11:09.386 16952 16952 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.multidex.MultiDex.install(MultiDex.java:178)
```

The AndroidManifest.xml is the 'default-generated by the plugin' one, which is used when no manifest-file is defined in the gradle-file (as the documentation says).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="de.package.of.application" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
    <application android:label="main-client" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        <activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" android:label="main-client" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <meta-data android:name="main.class" android:value="de.package.of.application.ClientApp"/>
            <meta-data android:name="debug.port" android:value="0"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

What I also tried so far:

- update IDE gluon-plugin for eclipse to recent version (2.4.0)
- generated a new project and compared the generated gradle-file and androidManifest.xml-file with my files from above -> I cannot see
  real differences except from my additional required lines.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Was your gradle file created by the latest version of the IDE plugin? I don't think so. The issue pops up again and again. Please make sure, you've got the MultiDexApplication integrated into your `AndroidManifest.xml`. You could updated your question and give us the content of your `src/android/AndroidManifest.xml`. Ok?

Comment: Thanks. This indeed looks ok. Comparing it to my test set-up I needed to solve an performance issue with, it looks quite similar to mine: If you want, compare it to this repository https://github.com/bgmf/example/tree/master/ExampleProject - I need multidex on it and it works on my personal Nexus 6 and a development Nexus 5.

Comment: It seems using the option 'keepRuntimeAnnotatedClasses false' is not a good idea for our application. As I understand the option removes all runtime-annotated classes, so reflection-things will not work. As our application is build on some injection/reflection-logic, the application fails to start because of missing some classes at startup. Removing the option from the gradle file+rebuild shows: com.android.dex.DexException: Too many classes in --main-dex-list, main dex capacity exceeded. Googled around and read a lot about it but I do not see how to solve it with javafxports. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have to admit: I don't know. There are only small differences, like differences like mobile plugin version and ordering. As I said: I used a generated Applikation (by the IDE plugin) as a base and never faced such issues. What is your target device?